# How to combine two groups by Index

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I need to combine two groups together. How should I do?

For example:

Table1

```
Index|Column1|Column2|Values
0    |      A|      B|    10
1    |      A|      B|    20
2    |      B|      B|    10
3    |      B|      B|    10
4    |      B|      A|    30
5    |      C|      C|    30
6    |      C|      C|    10
7    |      C|      D|    10
8    |      C|      D|    20
```

---

Group1 of Column1 sum

```
Index|Values(sum)
A    |         30
B    |         50
C    |         70
```

---

Group2 of Column2 sum

```
Index|Values(sum)
A    |         30
B    |         50
C    |         40
D    |         30
```

---

Now I want to combine Group1 and Group2 together and add one column back to Table1 like this below.

Combine

```
Index|Values
A    |    60
B    |   100
C    |   110
D    |    30
```

---

Table1

```
Index|Column1|Column2|Values|Combine
0    |      A|      B|    10|     60
1    |      A|      B|    20|     60
2    |      B|      B|    10|    100
3    |      B|      B|    10|    100
4    |      B|      A|    30|    100
5    |      C|      C|    30|    110
6    |      C|      C|    10|    110
7    |      C|      D|    10|    110
8    |      C|      D|    20|    110
```

Answer (score 3):

You can melt the two columns and then aggregate. Map the values to Column1 in the nest step

```
mapper = df.melt('Values',['Column1', 'Column2']).groupby('value')['Values'].sum().to_dict()
df['Combine'] = df['Column1'].map(mapper)

    Column1 Column2 Values  Combine
index               
0   A       B       10      60
1   A       B       20      60
2   B       B       10      100
3   B       B       10      100
4   B       A       30      100
5   C       C       30      110
6   C       C       10      110
7   C       D       10      110
8   C       D       20      110
```

Answer (score 1):

If your data frame is called `df`, you could let

```
v = df.groupby('Column1').Values.sum().add(df.groupby('Column2').Values.sum(), fill_value=0)
df['Combine'] = v.loc[df['Column1']].values
```

Answer (score 0):

`df['Values1'] = df.groupby('Column1')['Values'].transform('sum')`

This would do grouping on Column1.

`df['Values2'] = df.groupby('Column2')['Values'].transform('sum')`

This would do it on Column2.
Next we can combine the results like below:

`df['Combine'] = df['Values1'] + df['Values2']`